# Error with resolution operator while referencing model type depending on dynamic variable (PHP 5.2)

Tags: php, yii, php-5.2, scope-resolution

**Background Information:**

I am trying to simplify the structure of my Yii app, by moving a common function from child classes into the base class they are extending from.

I moved the `loadModel($id)` function from the User (child) controller into the Base controller.

Before, in UserController.php. This works:

```
public function loadModel($id) {
    $model = User::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

After, I removed the above function, and placed it into the Controller.php, which is inherited by UserController, and many others:

```
public function loadModel($id) {
    $type = modelname(); // returns a string, i.e.: "User"
    $model = $type::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

**Problem:**

I have tried this out on my local PC, running PHP 5.4.4, which ***works as expected***, but when this is uploaded into the testing server running PHP 5.2, this throws a HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error). On viewing the error logs, the error was `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` error, which is referring to the [resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#PHP) on the third line.

**Question:**

- Any reason why the resolution operator fails on PHP 5.2 in this case? and,
- Are there any workarounds to making this work with the same effect?

=================

**Additional Information:**

The global modelname function I am using, which returns the model name, i.e.: "User":

```
function modelname() {
    return Yii::app()->controller->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in
>   simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to
>   static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.
>
> When referencing these items from outside the class definition, use
>   the name of the class.
>
> **As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a
>   variable.** The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent
>   and static).

Basically, I had to upgrade the PHP version to be able to reference a class dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to upgrade to reference the class dynamically. Yii does it without and yii supports PHP 5.2. If you are interested, I can see if I can dig up how it is done, but I've run into the same problem and resolved it on PHP 5.2

Edit:
Ok, here's the info. I posted the original info on a [Yii wiki page.](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/9/how-to-log-changes-of-activerecords/#c7621)

Here's the code that returns a Yii singleton model:

```
    $thisModel = call_user_func($modelname, 'model');
```

But, per DCoder, it looks like `CActiveRecord::model($modelname)` will also work:

Yii info here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#model-detail

Comment: You're thinking of `CActiveRecord::model($type)`.